# Will gym rings attached on super long strips make it harder to do the elements?

Tags: rings

I know the standard length is 3-4m above the ground for Olympic rings. but imagine  hanging on super long (100m) straps. Will it make it super hard to do Iron Cross, Maltese, even L-sit?

[image: Image of a man on the rings, with an indication that the straps would be 100m long]

Answer (score 3):

[It sounds like it would be very hard](https://www.gymnasticbodies.com/forum/topic/8818-rings-cables-length-does-it-affect/).

> It's fairly simple. If you look at the angle that the strap makes from neutral to any displaced position it will be smaller the longer the straps are. This is directly related to how much the rings must lift from the floor as the straps move in or out, In other words how much they must go uphill.
>
> The less they go uphill the more easily they will move = the more unstable they will feel.

They go on to describe it essentially working like a pendulum. The longer the pendulum, the harder it is to bring it to a complete rest.

> I think this could also be due to the length of the pendulum. Because if we exert a small force on both a long and a short pendulum ( in this instance one of the straps), the short pendulum will come to rest first.
>
> This is due to the circumference of the arc length (or how far the ring has to travel to gain vertical height, which requires work to be done to fight gravity). Because with each oscillation the ring can travel furthur [sic] they become more unstable. This means a minute force from your muscles trying to stabilize causes the rings to travel furthur [sic], which you then have to control.

Comment: Also, the ropes will swing in waves heavily due to them being heavier than the weight trying to keep them straight.